# Line numbers mismatch when reading a file in python

Tags: python, sed

I have a script as follows:

```
counter = 0
with open(output_file, 'a') as f_out:
    with codecs.open(data_file, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
        for line in f:
            counter += 1
            try:
                created_at = datetime.strptime(line[:first_colon], '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            except ValueError:
                log('Parse Error at line ' + str(counter))
                continue
            f_out.write(str(counter)+','+line+'\n')
```

When I inspect the output file and the corresponding line in the data file using

```
sed -n '#counterhere#p' data_file
```

, I find the line does not match.

Any idea about what happens here?

Edit:

For instance, in data file we have:

```
2016-03-18,Content1
2016-03-#J,Content2
2016-03-20,Content3
```

Thus in output file we have:

```
1,2016-03-18,Content1
3,2016-03-20,Content3
```

So that I can locate the exact line in data file using something like:

```
sed -n '3p' data_file
```

And it should return "Content3" when it doesn't.

In small file it all goes fine. Yet because I'm running it on large files, it is hard for me to debug it.

Comment: well you are adding an extra `\n` to the line which would already have a new line on it so that might be causing the issue.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen To my perception, the bug lies in counting lines from the data file, in which there are blank lines and also unicode strings. The style of the output file is correct.

Comment: was trying to debug this, but your code snippet doesn't create output files like you describe - with a bit of tweaking to make it run for me, it created `1,2016-03-18,Content1

1,2016-03-18,Content1

3,2016-03-20,Content3
`, with a newline in between each. Perhaps your code sample doesn't quite reflect your real problem?

Comment: @srowland Thanks for the hint. It was an error and I corrected it...

Comment: no probs - you are definitely adding a newline with '\n' on my platform, which might be throwing things out.

Comment: what is the exact problem you are trying to fix by the way? Is it the numbering of lines in the output file, as this is down to incrementing the counter variable even when you fail to parse a line. Or is it that the line with #J in it doesn't parse and therefore you don't have 3 lines in the output?

Comment: @srowland The newline might be a OS-dependent problem. Well, the exact problem I'm trying to fix is that I need to correspond line number in the output file with the exact line in the data file and it doesn't work. It's like when I see a line in the output file, I know how to locate the original one in the data file.

Comment: @srowland Lines from the data file aren't all properly formatted, which I guess might be problematic. I couldn't think of any cause of this issue, since the way Python iterates through text files is the same with that of the command "sed".

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example I've been using:

```
import codecs
from datetime import datetime

output_file = 'out.csv'
data_file = 'data.csv'
first_colon = 9

counter = 0
with open(output_file, 'a') as f_out:
    with codecs.open(data_file, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
        for line in f:
            counter += 1
            try:
                created_at = datetime.strptime(line[:first_colon], '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            except ValueError:
                print('Parse Error at line ' + str(counter))
                continue
            f_out.write(str(counter)+','+line)
```

Using `data.csv` file of:

```
2016-03-18,Content1
2016-03-#J,Content2
2016-03-20,Content3
```

Gives `out.csv`:

```
1,2016-03-18,Content1
3,2016-03-20,Content3
```

Which has the correct line number for the correct source line in `data.csv`. So these line numbers can be used to find the information in the source file:

```
sed -n '3p' data.csv
```

gives me

```
2016-03-20,Content3
```

Hope this helps move things forward.